# How to make this table look more compact and nicer?

Tags: tables

```
%\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{longtable}

%\title{A longtable example}

%\begin{document}

%\begin{center}


\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{WITS and ASUS Type of Treatment by Offender Type}
    \label{ASUS-WITS_treatment_table} 
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \cline{2-7}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{WITS} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ASUS} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Treatment\textbackslash{}Offender Type} &
    Probationer &
    Parolees &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Maximum-term\\ Released Prisoners\end{tabular} &
    Probationers &
    Parolees &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Maximum-term\\ Released Prisoners\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Outpatient}              &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Intensive Outpatient}    &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Day Treatment}           &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Partial Hospitalization} &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Short Term Residential}  &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Inpatient}               &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Long Term Residential}   &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Therapuetic Community}   &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%\end{center}

%\end{document}
```

The codes above give out this table: [image]

I was wondering how I can make the table more centered and look more compact.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as it asks something that will most likely request opinion-based answers (as "more centered and look more compact" is subjective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{WITS and ASUS Type of Treatment by Offender Type}
    \label{ASUS-WITS_treatment_table} 
    \centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllllll}
   \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{WITS} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ASUS} \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
    \thead{Treatment\textbackslash{}\\Offender Type} &
    \thead{Prob.} &
    \thead{Parol.} &
    \thead{Max.-term\\ Rel. Pris.} &
    \thead{Prob.} &
    \thead{Parol.} &
    \thead{Max.-term\\ Rel. Pris.}\\ 
    \midrule
    Outpatient              &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    Intensive Outpatient    &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    Day Treatment           &         &        &        &         &        &        \\  
    Partial Hospitalization &         &        &        &         &        &        \\
    \addlinespace 
    Short Term Residential  &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    Inpatient               &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    Long Term Residential   &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    Therapuetic Community   &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{7}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{Prob. = Probationer; Parol. = Parolees; Max.-term Rel. Pris. = Maximum-term Released Prisoners}\\
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering how do I keep all the vertical and horizontal lines of the table? I added ``\hline`` to the cells of the table but only getting horizontal lines.

Comment: Since the title of your question contains "nicer", I was under the impression, you not only wanted to make the table fit into the textwidth, but also improve its design. This is why I removed most of the lines, since they don't add to the readability of the table.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \caption{WITS and ASUS Type of Treatment by Offender Type}
        \label{ASUS-WITS_treatment_table} 
        \centering
        \noindent\hspace{-3cm}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{WITS} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ASUS} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\makecell[l]{Treatment\\ \textbackslash{}Offender Type}} &
        Probationer &
        Parolees &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Maximum-term\\ Released Prisoners\end{tabular} &
        Probationers &
        Parolees &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Maximum-term\\ Released Prisoners\end{tabular} \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Outpatient}              &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Intensive Outpatient}    &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Day Treatment}           &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Partial Hospitalization} &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Short Term Residential}  &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Inpatient}               &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Long Term Residential}   &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Therapuetic Community}   &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with more compact? Adjust it to page -> `adjustbox`
Also I would right align the caption it with the table and in my opinion a table looks better without too many lines especially vertical

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\title{A longtable example}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{WITS and ASUS Type of Treatment by Offender Type}
    \label{ASUS-WITS_treatment_table} 
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{llll:lll}
   
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{WITS} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ASUS} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Treatment\textbackslash{}Offender Type} &
    Probationer &
    Parolees &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Maximum-term\\ Released Prisoners\end{tabular} &
    Probationers &
    Parolees &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Maximum-term\\ Released Prisoners\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Outpatient}              &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Intensive Outpatient}    &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Day Treatment}           &         &        &        &         &        &        \\  
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Partial Hospitalization} &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Short Term Residential}  &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Inpatient}               &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Long Term Residential}   &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Therapuetic Community}   &         &        &        &         &        &        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using resizebox on a table will lead to inconsistent font sizes and line widths through the document. I therefore recommend to not use resizebox. Instead you could use a smaller font size, such as \small.

Comment: Since you edited your answer to switch from `\resizebox` to `adjustbox`:  Your code is not compilable any more since the `adjustbox` package is missing. Apart from that, `adjustbox`, just as `\resizebox` and `\scalebox`, leads to inconsistent font sizes.